# Background image in td for Outlook 2007

Tags: html, outlook-2007

I've looked at the question at [background image on TD in Outlook 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587328/background-image-on-td-in-outlook-2007). I can't get a background image to display in a td element.

I've also looked at http://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=3862 and tried it but no joy.

Only a fragment of my code:

```
<td height="100%" valign="top" background="myimage.gif" alt="" bgcolor="#FFFF00">
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block;width:51px;height:10px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border:0;z-index:-1;' src="myimage.gif" />
<![endif]-->

... td contents...

</td>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [background image on TD in Outlook 2007](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587328/background-image-on-td-in-outlook-2007)

Comment: Sorry, duplicate questions are discouraged on SO, voting to close as duplicate. I'll make a small edit in the original question so it bumps to the top. If it's really, really important to you, you could also start a bounty

Comment: Ok that'd be great thanks. I can't set a bounty yet, only earned 73% of that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Width Backgrounds on Outlook '07/'10/'13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got around this by increasing the height of the image accordingly to make it fit. I didn't use VML at all.

Answer (score 1):

take out the inline behavior and display on the vml element (nice try, I tried that one too) and make sure this is in your header:

```
<head>
<xml:namespace ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" prefix="v"/>
<style type="text/css">v\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML);}</style>
<?xml:namespace prefix = v />
</head>
```

I hope this saves someone the ~8 hours it took me to find