# Newsletter background image not showing up in my outlook 2007

Tags: php, html, newsletter, outlook-2007

I've called background images in my html newsletter and these images are not showing up in my outlook and in gmail also:

Code:

```
<td style="font-family: calibri;font-size:16px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;padding-left:4px;border-top:1px solid #039AE0;border-bottom:1px solid #039AE0;border-left:1px solid #039AE0;border-right:1px solid #039AE0;border-radius:25px;background: url('http://mysite/newsletter/images/truy.jpg') repeat-x;text-align:center;" height="40" >3900 AED</td>
```

Comment: are the images already on live?

Comment: This might [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587328/background-image-on-td-in-outlook-2007) From experience, some versions of outlook have issues with background images.

Comment: @kevinabelita images are on the live :)

Answer (score 1):

Using background images is not supported by most email clients. There is very limited use of CSS when it comes to emails.

There is some information here as to how you can get around it - http://blog.mailchimp.com/background-images-and-css-in-html-email/

Comment: i am calling background image for a TD with repeat x;not able to find a cleat cut solution for these issue..read lot of forums

Comment: Do as mentioned in the link I gave. Dont use CSS, use the `<TD>` `background=""`. You can do `background-repeat: repeat-x` in the style which may work on some email platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Background images do work across major email clients. The difficulty, as you've discovered is with Outlook. Outlook only supports background images in either the body tag or by using VML. See this similar answer:

[Background images not working in Outlook 2007 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441034/background-images-not-working-in-outlook-2007-and-later/16531726#16531726)