# How to set background image to an div tag (Must support in outlook 2007 and 2010)

Tags: html, css, outlook

Please anybody help to sort this issue. I have been trying to set a background image to a div tag (to send html mail), which is not supported in outlook 2007. After I read some articles I understand the background-image is not supported in outlook 2007.

Is there any other good method to solve this?

I already tried the following methods. But these are not working in outlook 2007

1. `<div  style="background-image:url(imagepath.png)">`
2. `<img   src="imagepath.png" />
      <div  style="position: absolute; top: 415px;">`

the above two methods not works for me .Please give an suggestion for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible. I use this to check the compatibility of CSS with the different email clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ and as you can see, background-image is not supported by Outlook.

I had a quick Google and came across this though which may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4627810/5392786

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `background-repeat:` property to your CSS rule.

```
<div  style="background-image:url(imagepath.png);background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
```

Source:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2008/07/body-background-images-outlook/

Comment: Remember to verify that your image path is correct!  ; )

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup of message bodies. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

They state the following:

> Two HTML elements that support a subset of the cascading style sheets properties are called out: `DIV` and `P`. `DIV` and `P` support a subset of Word 2007–supported cascading style sheet.